# How would I modify this code to make it suitable for a subclass?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, subclass, ccsprite

I have got this code that I used before, but now that it I have subclassed my sprite, I need to adapt it. Here it is:

```
-(void)moveRandom:(CCSprite*)mos
{
CGPoint randomPoint = ccp(arc4random()%480, arc4random()%320);
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(randomPoint));

CGPoint start = mos.position;
CGPoint end = randomPoint;
float distance = ccpDistance(start, end);
float duration = distance/450;
[mos runAction:
 [CCSequence actions:
  [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:duration position: randomPoint],
  [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
     [self performSelector:@selector(moveRandom:) withObject:mos afterDelay:0.5];
 }],
  nil]
 ];
}
```

What it does is that it chooses a random point on the screen, then it makes it so that the sprite moves at a constant speed between the two points, then it moves the sprite, and re-calls the method.

EDIT:
The reason that I want to do this is because I will instances of this sprite in my sprite's layer, and they are all going to be doing this method.

**Should I not be incorporating this in my CCSprite subclass, but more like my sprite's layer?**

Comment: Why do you consider doing so? Without that info your question can not be answered, it's like asking a stranger "Why did I turn left at the last intersection?". Dude, I don't even know where you are going. ;)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Good point, I was tired at the time. I'll add that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, in an OO way, the subclass of CCSprite would be responsible for itself (encapsulated).  So when you wanted the sprite to move you (or the object to which the subclass of CCSprite is exposed) would call its `moveRandom` method.  Then it would do the moving all on its own without the CCLayer to which it's attached knowing anything about how it achieved the move.

The method in the subclass of CCSprite would look like this:

```
@interface AnotherSprite : CCSprite {}

-(void) moveRandom;

@implementation AnotherSprite

-(void)moveRandom
{
    CGPoint randomPoint = ccp(arc4random()%480, arc4random()%320);
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(randomPoint));

    CGPoint start = self.position;
    CGPoint end = randomPoint;
    float distance = ccpDistance(start, end);
    float duration = distance/450;
    [self runAction:
        [CCSequence actions:
            [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:duration position: randomPoint],
                [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
                    [self performSelector:@selector(moveRandom) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
                }],
        nil]
    ];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, but would there be a way to change it so that it would still work in a subclass that contains all of my enemy sprites? For example, my subclass is called enemy.h , and in there there are all of the different types of enemy sprites, and their corrsponding methods?

Answer (score 0):

To satisfy all of your apparent requirements, I would make this an extension to the CCSprite class itself, which would require:

```
@interface CCSprite ( MyClassExtensions )
- ( void ) moveRandom;
@end
```

and use the same implementation in @Jon's response, modifying the @implementation line appropriately....  This way, you can use this method for **all** sprites, regardless of where they occur in your application.

I hope that this helps....